# Why does 「でも」make question words mean 'any'?

Tags: meaning, particle-でも

いつ、どう、どれ、どこ、だれ、なに、etc. are all question words.

However, いつでも、どうでも、どれでも、どこでも、だれでも、なんでも、etc, all mean 'Any ___'.

What's making this happen? Is it just a special exception that evolved over time, or is there some reason for this considerable shift in meaning?

I ask as while I'm still not 100% when it comes to the particles で、も、and でも, I still don't get what's going on here.

Comment: `何` is a concept of `indefinite` and `いつ` → `何時` `どこ` → `何処` in Kanji. Using these as question words is a special case. Because `あなた-でも-いい` is a same usage of `でも`, those are not special exceptions, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure that someone can give a more specific etymological answer but も as a particle is appended to the て form of です, sort of like 何をしても, so it *isn't* two particles で and も. You're dealing with ~ても in this case.

Basically 何でも means "no matter what," which has the same functional meaning as "anything" in a lot sentences

> 中華なら何でもいい
>
> (if it's Chinese food, no matter what it is, I'll eat it / **anything** is fine)

いつでも、no matter when <--> anytime

どうでも, no matter how <--> anyhow

You get the picture.

Comment: You gave an ambiguous example sentence.  「中華街なら何でもいい。」 can just as easily mean "Any Chinatown will do."

Comment: actually it isn't ambiguous. I meant to just write 中華 and not 中華街. so you're correct. but the core grammar wasn't the ambiguous part anyway